# Delaying falling edge, and faster rising edge for output signal

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl

I'm trying to take an incoming signal to use as an output, but that output (active low) needs to be enabled about 20ns after the incoming signal goes low, and then go high again about 20ns before the incoming signal goes high. I'm using a 50MHz clock, so just one cycle is needed on either end.

What I've tried:

```
input signal_in; //incoming signal, active low
input clk; //50MHz clock, 20ns cycles
output signal_out_n; //output, active low

reg delay_sig;
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
   delay_sig  <= signal_in;
end

wire fallingEdge <= delay_sig & !signal_in; //if delay is 1, and signal is 0, we have incoming falling edge
wire risingEdge  <= !delay_sig & signal_in; //if delay is 0, and signal is 1, we have incoming rising edge

assign signal_out_n = ??
```

How do I assign this output so that falling, rising and incoming signals are accounted for? I've tried:

```
signal_out_n = {fallingEdge,risingEdge,signal_in}==3'b000 ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
```

... where fallingEdge and risingEdge would both be a 0 when neither is upcoming, so we'd go low when signal_in goes low. But I'm sure this needs to be done differently...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `signal_in` is not synchronous to `clk` within the FPGA then your `delay_sig` DFF can go metastable. Saying you want to extend by 20 ns and that's 1 `clk` period, you're seeing the logic circuit in simplistic and unrealistic terms. Unless there's a lot of top-flight synchronisation going on, you should step back and examine what you actually got. You are best off with some squared paper and a pencil to draw timing diagrams with best/worst case timing, then paper and pencil to sketch out the circuit you'll actually need. Finally, right at the end, only then represent that circuit in Verilog.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I assume your input is asynchronous to the clk. The following circuit can generate a delay on the falling edge and almost no delay on the rising edge.

[image]

The falling edge delay can vary between 1-2 clk cycles because the input is asynchronous to the clk. The delay won't be fixed.

You cannot generate an output that goes high before the input goes high. At best, you can make the output go almost when input goes high (after some combo delay) like in the circuit above. If you do need to generate an output which rises before the input, you can delay the input signal like in the picture below. The rising edge output is early w.r.t the delayed input and falling edge is delayed w.r.t the delayed input. The above circuit needs some modifications to achieve this.

[image]